# preg_match_all not work

Tags: php, preg-match-all

```
preg_match_all('/<img(.*)width="9" height="9" alt="(.*)" title="" />/' , $html , $sources );
foreach($sources[1] as $alt){
echo $alt."<br\>";
}
```

I want to list all alt tags values matched from a html page in all image
whats wrong?

I want to use regex not dom.

Answer (score 1):

Please [consult the php documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match-all.php) for a correct`preg_match_all` call. You need to provide regex delimiters!

Also, your problem description is not very specific so if you want any more help you'll need to rewrite your question posting.

Comment: What does't understand? I want to match every alt values in some images which have width=9 and height=9

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the / of the img tag :

```
preg_match_all('/<img(.*)width="9" height="9" alt="(.*)" title="" \/>/' , $html , $sources );
```

Otherwise it is considered as the end of your refex.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without knowing the exact html source, hard to tell. But there are multiple issues, and a good example why newcomers should not use regular expressions for that purpose:

- It will only ever match if the HTML attributes occur in this very particular order.
- Should the alt= and title= tags be switched in the souce, it will fail.
- Should the tag not end with the redundant `/>`, it will also not match.
- It can only detect the strings in the source if there is always exactly one space between the attributes. If there is a line-break in your HTML source, or a tab somewhere, or two spaces, ... (see `\s*`)
- The `(.*)` should be `(.*?)` in any case. Preferrably however one uses `[^>]+` or `[^"]+` for this use.
- The `#e` eval flag has no use in preg_match_all.

Answer (score 0):

you're just being **stubborn**, use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), or similar, to parse html.

ex:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.scroogle.org/');

    // Find all images
    foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
           echo $element->src . '<br>';
           echo $element->alt. '<br>';
```